# Elminiar hijo XML desde PHP

Tags: php, xml

Tengo un archivo php para eliminar un nodo de un xml.
A este archivo (eliminar.php), le paso los valores para que al recorrer el xml los compruebe y elimine el nodo correcto.
El xml lo leo con SimpleXML y lo recorro con un foreach, pero no consigo eliminarlo.
Os dejo el código completo:

```
        if($_GET["num_emp"] && $_GET["sala"] && $_GET["dia"] && $_GET["mes"] && $_GET["ano"]  && $_GET["hora_inicio"]){
            $xml = leer_reservas();
            foreach($xml->reserva as $reserva){
                if($reserva->sala == $_GET["sala"] && $reserva->empleado == $_GET["num_emp"] && $reserva->dia == $_GET["dia"] && $reserva->mes == $_GET["mes"] && $reserva->ano == $_GET["ano"] && $reserva->hora_inicio == $_GET["hora_inicio"]){
                    //BORRAR CHILD y GUARDAR xml
                }
            }
            /*
            $reservas->asXML('reservas.xml');
            echo '<script>
                    parent.location.reload();
                 </script>';
            */
        }
    function leer_reservas(){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("reservas.xml");
        return $xml;
    }
```

Comment: Intenta algo así: `if ($reserva->sala ==   ...) { $dom=dom_import_simplexml($reserva); $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom); }`

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano te juro que probé con "dom_import_simplexml($reserva);" y no me funcionaba... Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro. Estaba preparando una respuesta documentada. Conviene que cuando alguien te ayude a resolver un problema invites a ese usuario a aportar una respuesta. En este caso convendría explicar lo que hace `dom_import_simplexml`, dejando los enlaces adecuados para referencia de futuros usuarios. Ten en cuenta que Stackoverflow no es un foro, es un sitio de ayuda para programadores y tu respuesta puede ayudar a otros que en un futuro tengan un problema parecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar esa parte del XML puedes valerte de **[`dom_import_simplexml`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dom-import-simplexml.php)**, el cual convierte ese nodo en un objeto `DOMElement`, pudiendo luego borrarlo con [`removeChild`](http://php.net/manual/es/domnode.removechild.php).

Sería tan simple como esto:

```
        foreach($xml->reserva as $reserva){
            if($reserva->sala == $_GET["sala"] && $reserva->empleado == $_GET["num_emp"] && $reserva->dia == $_GET["dia"] && $reserva->mes == $_GET["mes"] && $reserva->ano == $_GET["ano"] && $reserva->hora_inicio == $_GET["hora_inicio"]){
                //BORRAR CHILD y GUARDAR xml
                $dom=dom_import_simplexml($reserva); 
                $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cedano he conseguido que funcione.
Os dejo el código completo:

```
    if($_GET["num_emp"] && $_GET["sala"] && $_GET["dia"] && $_GET["mes"] && $_GET["ano"]  && $_GET["hora_inicio"]){
        $xml = leer_reservas();
        foreach($xml->reserva as $reserva){
            if($reserva->sala == $_GET["sala"] && $reserva->empleado == $_GET["num_emp"] && $reserva->dia == $_GET["dia"] && $reserva->mes == $_GET["mes"] && $reserva->ano == $_GET["ano"] && $reserva->hora_inicio == $_GET["hora_inicio"]){
                $dom=dom_import_simplexml($reserva);
                $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
            }
        }
        $xml->asXML('reservas.xml');
        echo '<script>
                parent.location.reload();
             </script>';
    }
    function leer_reservas(){
        $reservas = simplexml_load_file("reservas.xml");
        return $reservas;
    }
```